# Velocity of Sound with an Increase in Pressure

Tags: pressure, acoustics, velocity, states-of-matter

**Why does the velocity of sound not increase with an increase in pressure?** Let me take an example. Suppose there exists a gas at some pressure. With an increase in pressure, it would turn into a liquid. Sound travels faster in a liquid, and thereby won't this contradict the fact that the velocity of sound does not depend upon pressure? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can't turn a gas into a liquid merely by increasing pressure.  You must also remove a lot of heat at the higher pressure, such that you remove the heat of compression and the heat of vaporization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure and density are proportional in gas. Sound speed depends on pressure AND density in opposite way, so the effect cancels out an the speed is only dependent of temperature and kind of gas. This is not related to sound speed in fluids, whir very high densities compared to gas